# How do I compute the power spectral density knowing the input signal autocorrelation modulated by a cosine with random phase?

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-transform

I have the following system:

$$S(t) = X(t) \cdot d(t)$$

where

$R_{XX}(\tau)=\frac{1}{2\pi}Sa(\frac{\tau}{2})cos(3\tau)$ and $d(t)=cos(2t + \theta)$ where $\theta \sim U[0,2\pi)$ and is independent of $X(t)$

I would like to compute $R_{SS}(\tau)$.

Normally, I would think to be given the autocorrelation of $d$, then I could apply the Winer-Khintchine theorem and using the fact that multiplication in time domain is convolution in frequency domain.  But, I am stumped where to begin given that I am given the autocorrelation of X(t) but not d(t).

$R_{SS}(t,\tau)=E[S(t)S(t+\tau)]$

$=E[X(t)d(t)X(t+\tau)d(t+\tau)]$

$=E[X(t)X(t+\tau) d(t)d(t+\tau)]$

$=E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]E[d(t)d(t+\tau)]$ via independence

$=R_{SS}(\tau)E[d(t)d(t+\tau)]$

Attempting to solve for 
$R_{dd}=E[d(t)d(t+\tau)]$,

$E[cos(2t+\theta)cos(2(t+\tau)+\theta)]$

Using product identities, I get,

$\frac{1}{2}E[cos(4t + 2\theta + 2\tau)]$ which I believe is zero.

Comment: At first what  you can define is $r_{SS}(t,\tau)=\mathbb{E}[S(t)\overline{S(t+\tau)}]$. If $U,V$ are independent then $\mathbb{E}[UV] = \mathbb{E}[U]\mathbb{E}[V]$. If $r_{SS}(t,\tau)$ doesn't depend on $t$ (eg. when $S$ is stationary) then you set $R_{SS}(\tau) = r_{SS}(0,\tau)$

Comment: I dont have U though, just the autocorrelation of U.

Comment: You have $\mathbb{E}[U]$ with $U = X(t) X(t+\tau)$ (assuming $\mathbb{E}[X(t)] = 0$, otherwise substract it from $X(t)$). $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate, if $X(t)$ is real it is unnecessary

Comment: What does the bar mean about s t + tau

Comment: I updated my derivation and examined your input but am still stuck.

Comment: $\cos A \cos B =\frac12 \cos (A+B)+\frac12\cos (A-B)$. In the latter $2t+\theta$ disappear so it is constant, the former is zero mean

Comment: Thank you.  I was using Ptolomy's identities and forgot there existed the product identities.

Comment: And did you make clear that $r_{XX}(t,\tau) = \mathbb{E}[(X(t)-\mathbb{E}[X(t)])\overline{(X(t+\tau)-\mathbb{E}[t+\tau])}]$ that is to say the very first step is to replace $X(t)$ by $X(t)-\mathbb{E}[X(t)]$

Comment: No, see my updated solution.  Is the last line correct?

Comment: $E[cos(2t+\theta)cos(2(t+\tau)+\theta)] = \frac{1}{2}E[cos(2\tau)]+\frac{1}{2}E[cos(4t + 2\theta + 2\tau)]= \frac{1}{2}cos(2\tau)+ 0$